# Passing filename dynamically - Python 3.6.5

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x

We trying to pass the filename dynamically in 'make_clustergrammer.py', each call the text file name will be different.

```
fileName = sys.argv[1:]
loadFile = ''.join(fileName)
decoded_string = bytes(loadFile, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape") # python3
```

load matrix tsv file

```
tempassign = decoded_string.replace('"','')
confilename = 'txt/' + tempassign + '.' + 'txt'
print(confilename )
net.load_file(confilename)
```

Error which i m getting as follows,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'txt/.txt'
1 . assigned variable is empty
2. I m communicating python script from nodejs.

Pls help me out, i got stuck with this more than a week.

Really, this clustergrammer is what needed exactly for our project.

We using MEAN(MongoDb, ExpressJS, Angular 4, NodeJs).

Actual prob is when i assign the argv[1:] to a variable and use that variable as parameter for 'net.load_file('filename')', it is empty.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05uat.png)

Hard code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrnKn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYVdE.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The script expects a file name to be passed as a command line argument. Apparently you are not passing a file name, so the variable

```
fileName = sys.argv[1:]
```

will be empty. Then `tempassign` will also be an empty string and the file name will be just "txt/.txt". Of course such file does not exist and you get the FileNotFound error.

Comment: I m concatenating in the below line, confilename = 'txt/' + tempassign + '.' + 'txt' \n
print(confilename ) \n
net.load_file(confilename). when i print, i m getting the expected file path, but when i pass it as argument it is empty("txt/.txt")